# SharePoint Hosted app installation

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I have created an sp-hosted app in SharePoint Online. This app is deploying in a Developer site, but I don't know how I can deploy my app in another site in my tenancy?

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure an App Catalog, there you can upload the .app file. Once done you will be able to install it in your webs.

Here is how to configure the App Catalog: [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161234(v=office.15)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161234%28v=office.15%29)

And here how to install an app from the app catalog: [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161231(v=office.15)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161231%28v=office.15%29)

Here is a good starting point for SP hosted app development: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161232%28v=office.15%29